# AngularJS, View is not getting updated on change in Modal value from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

View(question_to_vote) is not getting updated when trying to change the modal value from the controller.

> View File: question_to_vote.html

```
<div class="alert alert-success text-center" ng-show="c.message.success">
<strong>Success!</strong> Question Posted
</div>
<button ng-click="c.insert_public_q()"> Active   </button>
```

> Controller:

```
app.controller("ques_controller",function($http,$state,$interval,$mdBottomSheet,$timeout){
  let vm = this;
  vm.message = {success:true};
  vm.message.success = false;

  vm.insert_public_q = function(){

  var upvote = {vote:1,name:"Mahesh"};
  $http({method:"post",url:"insert-top-downvote",data:{upvote:upvote}}).success(function(result){

         vm.message.success = true;

      });


})
```

});

> Route

```
var app = angular.module("around_a",['ui.router','ngMaterial']);

app.config(function($interpolateProvider,$stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){

    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[').endSymbol(']]');

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider
    .state('add_ques.questions_to_vote',{
      url: '/questions-to-vote',
      templateUrl:'questions_to_vote.html',
      controller:'ques_controller as c'
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you checked that your http success handler is being called?

Comment: Also you can check angular scope.apply. But it should not be required

Comment: Yes, If I am putting alert("success") in the success function, it is working.

Comment: You mean `vm.message.success` is not getting updated & `ng-show` doesn't show an element??

Comment: Abhishek, If you allow, I can share my screen with you. If you can help  me ??

Comment: c.message.success should it be message.success

Comment: @PankajParkarL: Yes, ng-show is not getting called as vm.message.success is not working. Although, I am using Controller as approach so I do think that Digest  Cycle ($scope.$apply()) does not make any sense.

Comment: @Boss: As I am using "ques_controller as c" approach so everything is accessible using c. only. I tried other things.. they are working but not this one ...

Comment: why would you want to use that approach ? that will be very messy in future

Comment: why dont you use scope variable ??  and print c.message.success in your view and check if it changes

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="alert alert-success text-center" ng-show="message.success">
<strong>Success!</strong> Question Posted
</div>
<button ng-click="c.insert_public_q()"> Active   </button>
```

There is not `c.message.success` its `message.success`

and oh yes another thing

```
app.controller("ques_controller",function($http,$state,$interval,$mdBottomSheet,$timeout,$scope){

  $scope.message = {success:true};
  $scope.message.success = false;

  $scope.insert_public_q = function(){

  var upvote = {vote:1,name:"Mahesh"};
  $http({method:"post",url:"insert-top-downvote",data:    {upvote:upvote}}).success(function(result){

         $scope.message.success = true;

      });


})
```

Comment: Use scope variable

Comment: There were some other Prototypical Inheritance problems which I was facing when I was using scope, so I have opted for this approach.

Comment: you could have used rootScope as well ... try the new code It will fix your issue

Comment: Can I use root scope in Controller as approach ?

Comment: yes you can ... if you want to access parent data then you can

Comment: other thing use camel case instead of  _ while naming and avoid using controller:'ques_controller as c' like this